# Saving selected listbox(binded) items to an array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

```
string[] chkItems = new string[4];    
string[] str = new string[4];
str[0] = txtID.Text;
str[1] = txtName.Text;
str[2] = txtEmail.Text;
itemCount = ltbxInterests.SelectedItems.Count;
for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount; i++)
{
  ltbxInterests.SelectedItems.CopyTo(chkItems, 0); 
  // here it is returning an exception 
  //"Object cannot be stored in an array of this type."
}
```

Please help me how to get out from this exception

Comment: What's the type of `chkItems` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues here, chkItems is defined as length 4 so you will get an exception if you try and put more than 4 items in. The source array SelectedItems is of type object so you would need to cast the result.

Assuming you are only putting strings into the listbox you could use (remember to reference System.Linq)

```
string[] str = new string[4];
str[0] = txtID.Text;
str[1] = txtName.Text;
str[2] = txtEmail.Text;

string[] chkItems = ltbxInterests.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

If you are wanting to limit to the first 4 items, you could replace the last line to

```
string[] chkItems = ltbxInterests.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().Take(4).ToArray();
```

Also you could shorten the code to use an array initializer (but this wil make str length 3 because you only have 3 items):

```
string[] str = new [] {
  txtID.Text,
  txtName.Text,
  txtEmail.Text,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedItems` is a collection of Object, then, in order to use `CopyTo` methods, `chkItems` must be an array of type object (i.e. `object[]`).

Otherwise, you can use LINQ to convert, for example, to a list of strings:

```
var selectedList = ltbxInterests.SelectedItems.OfType<object>()
                                              .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You chould check the Type of > chkItems .